# 403 error SharePoint Custom feature activation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Hi When i try to activate my branding feature i am getting 403 error .I am deploying my css script files into layouts folder .

I am not able to understand where i was wrong it is working in all the test environments but not in production .

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        // Get the SPWeb we're being activated in.
        var web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

        if (null != web)
        {

            // Get the Site Collection root path to get the master page gallery.
            string siteCollectionRoot = web.Site.RootWeb.Url;

            // Set the Site Master to Custom.master
            var siteMaster = new Uri(siteCollectionRoot +
                                     "/_catalogs/masterpage/" +
                                     "MYCUSTOM.Master");
            web.CustomMasterUrl = siteMaster.AbsolutePath;

            // Set the System Master to Custom.master
            var systemMaster = new Uri(siteCollectionRoot +
                                       "/_catalogs/masterpage/" +
                                       "MYCUSTOM.Master");
            web.MasterUrl = systemMaster.AbsolutePath;

            // Clear the Alternate CSS
            web.AlternateCssUrl = string.Empty;


            // Save the changes back to the web
            web.Update();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a few things, I would start with allow unsafe updates and then move on to elevating privileges as normally in dev environments you have full access. The code snippets incorporates the allow unsafe updates.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        // Get the SPWeb we're being activated in.
        var web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        if (null != web)
        {

            // Get the Site Collection root path to get the master page gallery.
            string siteCollectionRoot = web.Site.RootWeb.Url;

            // Set the Site Master to Custom.master
            var siteMaster = new Uri(siteCollectionRoot +
                                     "/_catalogs/masterpage/" +
                                     "MYCUSTOM.Master");
            web.CustomMasterUrl = siteMaster.AbsolutePath;

            // Set the System Master to Custom.master
            var systemMaster = new Uri(siteCollectionRoot +
                                       "/_catalogs/masterpage/" +
                                       "MYCUSTOM.Master");
            web.MasterUrl = systemMaster.AbsolutePath;

            // Clear the Alternate CSS
            web.AlternateCssUrl = string.Empty;


            // Save the changes back to the web
            web.Update();
           web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Truezplaya I have added allowunsafeupdates and i am target the current web not the rootweb url i have changed this line from
            string siteCollectionRoot = web.Site.RootWeb.Url;                        TO        string siteCollectionRoot = web.Url; . NOw it is working fine thanks for ur answer